# controlling autocad with python: pyautocad does nothing

Tags: python, autocad

I wish to be able to draw lines and rectangles on autocad via python. I am using pyautocad, however, nothing happens when I try to draw a line (not even an error). I'm just trying to get the example code to work. Is this an issue with pyautocad not working with newer versions of autocad? I'm a novice at python, so I do not know whats wrong.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python")
print (acad.doc.Name)
p1=APoint(0,0)
p2=APoint(10,10)
acad.model.AddLine(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Does anything appear when you perform a `REGEN` in AutoCAD?

Comment: Nothing appears after I perform REGEN

Answer (score 0):

When you run the commands, Autocad must to be open, this aplies for some commands, for example for "acad.doc.Name".